# How to save data in json file using node where path is located in module?

Tags: node.js, json

Here is the code:

```
updatearr = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('../modules/stores/data.json', "utf-8"));
```

> fs.writeFileSync('../modules/stores/data.json', stringifyData);

I am unable to write and read like this, as it is showing **there is no path or directory**

I tried **path, resolve, dirname**... Please help me thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

var path = require("path");

> var storeinfopath = path.join(__dirname, "../Storeinfo/storeinfodata.json");

fs.readFileSync(storeinfopath);

> fs.writeFileSync(storeinfopath);

worked this I wrote like this and placed the path on the same module which has controller and route
[My Vs code project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyVLJ.png)